# While ⇋ For convertibility and feasibility

Tags: for-loop, while-loop

We know that `while` and `for` are the most frequently used loop syntax for many programming and scripting languages. Here I would like to ask some questions regarding convertibility and feasibility of using `while` vs `for` loop.

Is `for` to `while` and vice versa transformation or conversion always possible? I mean suppose one used `while` loop for some functionality and I want to replace `while` with `for` or say vice-versa, then Is while ⇋ for transformation/conversion always possible (also interested in knowing the feasibility)? It would be helpful of I can refer If any research regarding this carried out.

I'm also interested in getting the general guidance for using `while` vs `for`. Also want to know if `while` has some advantages over `for` and vice versa.

<sup>Note: I've this question for log time, I thought -- being a great programming site, this question can be useful here. If the question is not suitable here. I'm unsure if this question is acceptable here, so requesting to consider it liberal; you can ask me to remove if such question hurts the quality of site :)</sup>

Comment: @DivyeshGausvami How? This question has [nothing to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) with SE!

Comment: @DivyeshGausvami No, it shouldn't be asked there. Please don't suggest such things.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer using Java as a reference, though this answer should also be completely valid for C, C#, C++ and many others.  If we consider the following `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < 10; ++i) {
    // do something, maybe involving i
}
```

We can see that the loop has 3 components:

```
int i=0;     initialization of loop counter
i < 10       criteria for loop to execute
++i          increment to loop counter
```

The following `while` loop is functionally equivalent to the above `for` loop:

```
int i=0;
while (i < 10) {
    // do something, maybe involving i
    ++i;
}
```

We can see that the main difference between this `while` loop and the `for` loop are that the declaration and initialization of the loop counter is outside the loop in the former case.  Also, we increment the loop counter inside the actual `while` loop.  The check for the loop continuing is still done inside the loop structure, as with `for` loops.

So a `for` loop can be thought of an enhanced `while` loop of sorts.  It frees us from having to create a loop counter outside the loop, and also we can increment/change the loop counter within the loop structure, rather than mixing such logic with the code of the loop body.